# Do vegans have higher testosterone levels?

Tags: veganism, health, nutrition

Do vegans have higher testosterone levels than non-vegans?

<sup>cf. "[Does eating soy lower testosterone?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1456/811)"</sup>

<sub>There are studies that show fasting increases T levels, too.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This [Allen & Key (2000)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/1C7174359EBA2ECAC1013298105E8298/S0954422400000718a.pdf/the-effects-of-diet-on-circulating-sex-hormone-levels-in-men.pdf) paper reviews multiple previous studies looking at testosterone levels of vegans compared to meat-eaters.  Only one study had a large enough sample size to actually show a "small but significant" increase in SHBG* and testosterone levels in vegan men compared to men who eat meat.  However, none of the studies showed any lasting health impacts as a result of this difference, which could be attributed to negative feedback loops where our bodies naturally compensate small changes in hormone production to maintain consistent levels.

> Concomitant with an increase in SHBG concentration among vegans compared with meat- eaters is the small increase in testosterone concentration (Key et al. 1990a; Pusateri et al. 1990; Allen et al. 2000), although Allen et al. (2000) was the only study large enough to detect signficant differences (P<0.05). One small study reported no differences in testosterone concentration between dietary groups (Deslypere & Vermeulen, 1984)

*SHBG stands for Sex Hormone Binding Globulin which is a protein produced by your liver that binds to our sex hormones, including testosterone. [Source linked here.](https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=167&ContentID=shbg_blood)

In summary, yes, there is some evidence that vegan men may have slightly higher testosterone levels than men who eat meat.  But it isn't a major health concern and further studies that aren't just observational would help answer this question with more accuracy.